# How to load values from array of dictionary into tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift

```
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : 3 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : DisplayName
      - value : Jim Seymour
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : Tags
      - value : Jim Seymour
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - key : Rownum
      - value : 1
  ▿ 1 : 3 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : DisplayName
      - value : Cliff Armstrong
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : Tags
      - value : Cliff Armstrong
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - key : Rownum
      - value : 2
```

How to store values from above array into tableview cell

```
var favoriteArrayList: NSArray = []

func configurationFavoriteCell (cell: TagsTableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath){

   cell.lblName?.text = favoriteArrayList[indexPath.row][value(forKey: "DisplayName")]

    }
```

Gives an Error type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: have you tried converting that to objects and then work your self  from there?

Comment: Can you show us the `JSON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `favoriteArrayList` object can be rather declared as `[[String : Any]]`. In that way, you won't get such error

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

The error states that the your `favoriteArrayList[indexPath.row]` returns an `Any`. You can cast/convert that into a dictionary or do what I suggested above.

And then when you have a dictionary, you may access its value by key.

`favoriteArrayList[indexPath.row]["DisplayName"]`

Now this might return an `Any` again, because based on your data, you have `Int`, and `String`, etc...

You can cast that to String since you are displaying in on a `UILabel`.

```
let displayName = favoriteArrayList[indexPath.row]["DisplayName"]
cell.lblName?.text = "\(displayName)"
```

---

Also, consider making a model out of your data. That's way better than this.